# how should I subtract from the previous value in the same variable?

Tags: php

**Problem**

The problem which I'm facing is am not able to subtract the lose from expected_weight dynamically. I want expected_weight to be changed until the playing_dates count finishes. Please refer to the expected output. Thanks in advance!

**Code:**

```
echo "<pre>";
        $benchmark = 96.5; //The first weight from which a person commits to lose their weight every week.
        $lose = 10; //Percentage of how much they commit to lose
        $lose_weight = ($benchmark/100)*$lose; //This gives how much they should lose every week to meet the target

        while($row_teams = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_select_teams)){
            echo"   {<br />";
            echo"       benchmark ==> ".$benchmark." Kg<br />";
            echo"       loss% ==> ".$lose."%<br />";
            echo"       lose_weight ==> ".$lose_weight." Kg<br /><br />";
            echo"       my_teams ==> ".$row_teams['t_name']."<br /><br />";
            $playing_dates = $row_teams['playing_dates'];
            $playing_dates = explode('|', $playing_dates);

            $date = date('Y');
            $noofweighins = count($playing_dates);
            echo"       noofweighins ==> ".$noofweighins."<br /><br />";
            $lose_atleast = round($lose_weight/$noofweighins, 2);
            $expected_weight = 0;
                for($k=0; $k<count($playing_dates);$k++){
                    $expected_weight = $benchmark - $lose_atleast;
                    if(substr($playing_dates[$k], -4)<=$date){
                        echo"       my_playing_dates ==> ".$playing_dates[$k]." to lose ==> ".$lose_atleast."<br />";
                        echo"       Expected weight ==> ".$expected_weight."<br /><br />";
                    }
                }
            echo"   }<br />";
        }
    }
    echo "</pre>";
```

**Output**

```
benchmark ==> 96.5 Kg
        loss% ==> 10%
        lose_weight ==> 9.65 Kg

        noofweighins ==> 10

        my_playing_dates ==> 16/02/2013 to lose ==> 0.965
        Expected weight ==> 95.535

        my_playing_dates ==> 18/02/2013 to lose ==> 0.965
        Expected weight ==> 95.535

        my_playing_dates ==> 13/03/2013 to lose ==> 0.965
        Expected weight ==> 95.535

        my_playing_dates ==> 20/03/2013 to lose ==> 0.965
        Expected weight ==> 95.535

        my_playing_dates ==> 27/03/2013 to lose ==> 0.965
        Expected weight ==> 95.535

        my_playing_dates ==> 03/04/2013 to lose ==> 0.965
        Expected weight ==> 95.535

        my_playing_dates ==> 10/04/2013 to lose ==> 0.965
        Expected weight ==> 95.535

        my_playing_dates ==> 17/04/2013 to lose ==> 0.965
        Expected weight ==> 95.535

        my_playing_dates ==> 24/04/2013 to lose ==> 0.965
        Expected weight ==> 95.535

        my_playing_dates ==> 01/05/2013 to lose ==> 0.965
        Expected weight ==> 95.535
```

**Expected Output**

```
benchmark ==> 96.5 Kg
        loss% ==> 10%
        lose_weight ==> 9.65 Kg

        noofweighins ==> 10

        my_playing_dates ==> 16/02/2013 to lose ==> 0.965
        Expected weight ==> 95.535 (96.5 - 0.965)

        my_playing_dates ==> 18/02/2013 to lose ==> 0.965
        Expected weight ==> 94.57 (95.535 - 0.965)

        my_playing_dates ==> 13/03/2013 to lose ==> 0.965
        Expected weight ==> 93.605 (94.57 - 0.965)

        my_playing_dates ==> 20/03/2013 to lose ==> 0.965
        Expected weight ==> 92.64 (93.605 - 0.965)

        my_playing_dates ==> 27/03/2013 to lose ==> 0.965
        Expected weight ==> 91.675 (92.64 - 0.965)

        my_playing_dates ==> 03/04/2013 to lose ==> 0.965
        Expected weight ==> 90.71 (91.675 - 0.965)

        my_playing_dates ==> 10/04/2013 to lose ==> 0.965
        Expected weight ==> 89.745 (90.71 - 0.965)

        my_playing_dates ==> 17/04/2013 to lose ==> 0.965
        Expected weight ==> 88.78 (89.745 - 0.965)

        my_playing_dates ==> 24/04/2013 to lose ==> 0.965
        Expected weight ==> 87.815 (88.78 - 0.965)

        my_playing_dates ==> 01/05/2013 to lose ==> 0.965
        Expected weight ==> 86.85 (87.815 - 0.965)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know PHP or anything and I only skim read your code, but what happens if you change `$expected_weight = $benchmark - $lose_atleast;` to `$expected_weight = $expected_weight - $lose_atleast;`

Comment: hey kells with a little alteration that works !! much appreciated

Comment: No Problem, glad I could help. Please could you +1 this post, I'm trying to build up some rep :)

Answer (score 0):

The desired result is:
`Expected weight ==> 87.815 (88.78 - 0.965)`

While 
`$benchmark = 96.5;` remains the same all the time.

And formula for that is:
`$expected_weight = $benchmark - $lose_atleast;`

It seems you must change your `$benchmark` in a loop to get the desired result.

Comment: I want to display expected weight for each playing date so the desired result is not Expected **weight ==> 87.815 (88.78 - 0.965)**. The desired result is mentioned in the Expected output.

Comment: You just wrote `87.815 (88.78 - 0.965)`. So `87.815 = 88.78 - 0.965` must be a match for `$expected_weight = $benchmark - $lose_atleast;` In the desired result you subtract from something different, not just `96.5`. But your `$benchmark` remains all the same.